# How to deal with functions and arrays which might differ between embedded system instances (per client) without resorting to pre-processor abuse?

Tags: c, embedded, c-preprocessor, organization

**Description**
I am the sole developer/designer/maintainer of an embedded system product for a controls company. I am a junior and there is no other engineer (of any discipline) in the company. The language is C (C99 standard) and the build system is CMake. The embedded system is a bare-metal STM32 MCU, with 8k RAM and 64k FLASH.
So far, the application has had one "instance", a super-set of all the features.

For example, an *alarm-module*, fed by an enum of all possible alarm topics, receives updates on all relevant data-points, handles all possible alarm topic triggers, keeps track of how long each alarm topic has been active for, and every alarm topic has its own audible buzzer pattern.

Now however, we are starting to develop instances of this embedded system for different clients, each with their own sub-set of features. Within the scope of the alarm module, this could mean they say "we don't care about ALARM2, but we do care about ALARM1 and ALARM3".

In an ideal case, such as a non-embedded system with much more RAM and non-volatile memory, the super-set modules would stay as is, and we simply have data in memory, functions, and paths that we never ever touch, or perhaps at run-time the system will read a configuration and allocate the appropriate memory. However, this is a constrained embedded system, and using malloc, having unnecessary RAM allocation, and dead code paths is not acceptable.

My goal is to introduce modularization such that there are core application modules (*alarm-module*) which link to a library (one per customer) of modules. This would mean we don't have to modify the application modules, but simply link it to the appropriate library for the appropriate customer.

**Concrete Example of the "Super-Set" Alarm Module**

```
#include "Counter.h" //Count time
#include "Buzzer.h" //Produce audible alarm patterns

typedef enum  
{
ALARM_TOPIC_NONE = 0U,
ALARM_TOPIC_TEMPERATURE_RANGE,
ALARM_TOPIC_PROBE1_FAULT,
ALARM_TOPIC_PROBE2_FAULT,
ALARM_TOPIC_PROBE3_FAULT,
ALARM_TOPIC_EXTERNAL,
ALARM_TOPIC_EXT_SERIOUS,
ALARM_TOPIC_MAX, //Used to set array-lengths and loop conditions
} Alarm_Topics_E;

//Holds the current "signal state" of an alarm topic.
//Separate from "raised state" of an alarm topic
static bool alarm_conditions[ALARM_TOPIC_MAX] = {
[ALARM_TOPIC_NONE]              = true,
[ALARM_TOPIC_TEMPERATURE_RANGE] = false,
[ALARM_TOPIC_PROBE1_FAULT]      = false,
[ALARM_TOPIC_PROBE2_FAULT]      = false,
[ALARM_TOPIC_PROBE3_FAULT]      = false,
[ALARM_TOPIC_EXTERNAL]          = false,
[ALARM_TOPIC_EXT_SERIOUS]       = false,
};
static bool raised_alarms[ALARM_TOPIC_MAX] = {0};

//Holds all counter structs for each alarm topic
static Counter_T alarm_counters[ALARM_TOPIC_MAX] = {0};

static const Buzzer_Pattern_E alarm_pattern_table[ALARM_TOPIC_MAX] = {
[ALARM_TOPIC_NONE]              = BUZZER_PATTERN_QUIET,
[ALARM_TOPIC_TEMPERATURE_RANGE] = BUZZER_PATTERN1,
[ALARM_TOPIC_PROBE1_FAULT]  = BUZZER_PATTERN2,
[ALARM_TOPIC_PROBE2_FAULT]      = BUZZER_PATTERN3,
[ALARM_TOPIC_PROBE3_FAULT]      = BUZZER_PATTERN4,
[ALARM_TOPIC_EXTERNAL]          = BUZZER_PATTERN3,
[ALARM_TOPIC_EXT_SERIOUS]       = BUZZER_PATTERN5,
};

void alarm_event_handler(const Args_Generic_T *generic_args) {
//Extract information from arguments, such as alarm_topic
    switch(alarm_topic)
    {
        case ALARM_TOPIC_NONE:         {/*Do something1*/}
        case ALARM_TOPIC_TEMPERATURE_RANGE: {/*Do something2*/}
        case ALARM_TOPIC_PROBE1_FAULT: {/*Do something3*/}
        case ALARM_TOPIC_PROBE2_FAULT: {/*Do something4*/}
        case ALARM_TOPIC_PROBE3_FAULT: {/*Do something5*/}
        case ALARM_TOPIC_EXTERNAL:     {/*Do something6*/}
        case ALARM_TOPIC_EXT_SERIOUS:  {/*Do something7*/}
    }
}

/* Below are other methods which handle updating alarm_condition, raised_alarm, and alarm_counters.
These methods are agnostic to specifics about the Alarm_Topics enum. 
For example, the method which handles alarm counters might look like such */
static void alarm_handle_condition(Alarm_Topics_E topic, bool alarm_condition) {
    /* business logic */
    if (topic < ALARM_TOPIC_MAX) {
        update_counter(&alarm_counters[topic]);
    }
    /* what do ya know more business logic */
}
```

Now, since the list of alarm topics might change per customer, I put the Alarm_Topics_E enum into its own module, which can be maintained per customer. Let's call this module *customer-config*.

However, the super-set *alarm-module* has arrays which use specific members of the enum as array designators
`[ALARM_TOPIC_PROBE3_FAULT] = BUZZER_PATTERN2`
and methods which directly reference the enum members
`case ALARM_TOPIC_PROBE3_FAULT: {/*Do something5*/}`.

If the customer decided they did not need a third probe, how close can I get to simply removing
`ALARM_TOPIC_PROBE3_FAULT` from the `Alarm_Topics_E` enum in the *customer-config* module, and get the *alarm-module* to properly acknowledge that change?

If I simply removed the enum member, the code will obviously not compile.

If I used pre-processor definitions/compilation flags in my *customer-config* such as
`#define USE_PROBE3`
then the *alarm-module* will be full of

```
#ifdef USE_PROBE3
/*activity related to probe3*/
#endif
```

If I moved the methods which are affected by this change into the *customer-config* module, and maintained them individually, I would also have to move multitudes of static-members of the *alarm-module* into the *customer-config* module, which don't feel like they belong there. Also, I would have to link the *customer-config* module against "Buzzer.h" which also doesn't feel right.

I am okay with potentially parsing a configuration structure on bootup, but I would still have to dynamically allocate array memory (HUGE NO-NO) and I would still have dead code paths (MINOR NO-NO but I can settle if necessary).

What are my options here? Do I truly have to resort to pre-processor abuse and wrap every affected part in the *alarm-module* with

```
#ifdef USE_PROBE3
/*activity related to probe3*/
#endif
```

That seems like my only option.

Have I already messed up in the organization/structure of my project?
Are there any open-source projects which deal with similar issues?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What other options have you looked at?  And regarding preprocessor abuse, replace `#ifdef CUSTOMER_USES_PROBE3` pr similar with `#ifdef ENABLE_PROBE3` or similar.  Do *not* tie the implementation of any one feature to any customer - tie them only to the feature they enable.  And keep each and every feature completely independent.  If you mix customers with features and/or make features interdependent, you will rapidly reach levels of complexity you will not be able too maintain.

Comment: Concerning the preprocessor statement, yeah, I most definitely was not planning on doing that. I wrote vague code for the purpose of this post.

As for what options I've tried, I started going down the route of enabling features with preprocessor defines, but it quickly turned the application modules very ugly with array initializations, switch statements, and entire functions wrapped in #ifdef ... #endif. This was a simple example with 7 independent features, there is a central module with 53 that is used all over the codebase. I would (most likely) x2 the line count of the entire project

Comment: Slight aside, but you probably don't need to wrap functions in `#ifdef`s, you can tell the linker to discard unused functions. This is the default configuration for STM32CubeIDE projects, or could be added to whatever tooling you use. Not an answer to your question, but maybe one less thing to worry about.

Comment: @pmacfarlane That certainly reads like the beginning of a possible answer...

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have a sketch of an answer in my mind, but it is 1am and I need to sleep. If nobody else answers before tomorrow evening, I'll try to answer.

Comment: Another option is to write a code generator. The input to the generator is the super set module, and list of features *not needed*. The generator outputs a C file with the unneeded features removed. Code generators are fine when you're working alone. But they can create a steep learning curve for new team members. So be sure to create a training manual, and keep it up to date as you add new features.

Comment: This sounds like something that perhaps should be handled by version control, not by source code. Use different branches per configuration, change as few source files as possible. Pre-processor #ifdef messes should be avoided, they don't scale well at all and if you keep adding them, then eventually everything turns impossible to read.

Comment: @Lundin In my experience, using version control branches for this has a risk of becoming just a different kind of poison. After certain number of branches it can turn into very time consuming merge work, which also doesn't scale well. It depends a lot on project organization though.

Comment: @user694733 Yeah but you can use a branch so that only a specific file is different between branches, and the rest of the project is 100% in sync with the trunk. Or for larger projects maybe put the local-specific "port" in a repo of it's own, so that the main application uses one repo and the "port" uses another. Version control is as powerful or dangerous as you let it be, [mandatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1296/).

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to define an array of event handler function pointers in the customer config file and use a `NULL` pointer for unused alarm handlers.  You can populate the array with common event handler functions from a shared module, or when needed define special case event handlers in the customer config module.

Then the "Super-Set" Alarm Module can be written to conditionally handle all of the alarm topics by replacing the `switch(alarm_topic)` statement with something like `if (alarm_event_handlers[alarm_topic]) { alarm_event_handlers[alarm_topic](args); }`.  This moves the logic from compile time to run time, but that's likely not a serious performance penalty for this application.  The "business logic" could be handled in a similar way, with another function pointer array.

For reference, this article describes other uses of function pointer arrays in embedded systems, including syntax examples:
https://barrgroup.com/embedded-systems/how-to/c-function-pointers

Comment: "This might not play nice with configuring the linker to discard unused functions, since it probably won't notice if you include a function pointer in an array." This shouldn't be a problem. As long as you reference a function by taking its address, it will get linked.

Comment: Good point.  I tried with GCC (`-ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections`) and that worked.  I'd recommend running a simple test with whichever tool you use.